# Looking for info on power set functor

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I was reading [here](http://sun.iwu.edu/~lstout/theoremlist/node12.html) about the various functors which take a set $S$ to its power set. In particular, there is the normal contravariant one, and two covariant ones, which the article calls $\exists$ and $\forall$.

I'd like a little more information on these functors and their properties. In particular, I'm interested in how these might play in to proofs in point-set topology...for instance the relation between the fact that $\forall$ plays nice with intersections and the fact that the regular forward image plays nice with intersections as long as at most one of the sets fails to be saturated.

I think these might provide a simple way to look at the rules we need to remember when we manipulate sets in point-set topology.

*(I previously wrote a poor version of this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230528/iso-information-on-powerset-functor), and this is a new version.)*

Comment: and I suggest again: you may be interested in topos theory.

Comment: $\exists_f$ is the left adjoint of pullback $f^{-1}$, $\forall_f$ is the right adjoint of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin How can a functor from $\mathsf{Set}^{op}$ to $\mathsf{Set}$ have an adjoint which is a functor from $\mathsf{Set}$ to $\mathsf{Set}$?

Comment: These are not functors between categories but rather monotone maps between posets.

Comment: Not the functor sending a set map to the inverse image function is the functor Zhen Lin is talking about, but the function $f^{-1}$ itself is the functor.

Comment: I wonder if there is a categorical explanation for the phenomenon, that the image functor $f$ preserves intersections (which are products in the category $\mathcal P(X)$ such that $f$ is left adjoint to $f^{-1}$) when at most one set is not saturated.

Comment: @StefanHamcke, seems to me that $\exists_f$ is left adjoint to $f^{-1}$ which is itself left adjoint to $\forall_f$ (seen as functors between the poset categories)... but I haven't verified it.

Comment: But I meant the phenomenon that the left adjoint $f$ (or $\exists_f$ as it's called here) preserves certain products. Being left adjoint only ensures that it preserves coproducts.

Comment: The observation you speak of is called Frobenius reciprocity: $\exists_f (X' \cap f^{-1} Y') = \exists_f X' \cap Y'$. It is equivalent to the fact that $f^{-1}$ preserves the Heyting implication.

Comment: @ZhenLin I thought Frobenius reciprocity was a result in representation theory.

Comment: For better or worse, that's what it's called here as well.

Comment: @ZhenLin It's difficult to find any info on this version because the rep theory one dominates all searches. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Not especially. You can start [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+reciprocity).